# I get errors when I try to do anything with migrations

Tags: drush, migrations

So I'm new to Drupal, and I'm trying to set up a migration. I followed a tutorial to import a basic csv as an article yesterday, that worked ok. There are no errors showing using the admin area of Drupal.

I tried to create a new migration following this guide (https://www.cmsdrupal.com/blog/how-import-data-csv-file-drupal-8-best-tools-and-approaches-you-can-use) but modified for a spreadsheet not a csv. I got to step 7 of the first section and Drush throws an error.

I've tried running a migrate status and that too throws an error

```
vendor/bin/drush migrate:status
```

The error I get is:

```
#1 /var/www/pnm.com/html/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/Migration.php(625): Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration->findMigrationDependencies(NULL)
#2 /var/www/pnm.com/html/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/MigrationPluginManager.php(122): Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration->getMigrationDependencies()
#3 /var/www/pnm.com/html/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/Commands/MigrateToolsCommands.php(701): Drupal\migrate\Plugin\MigrationPluginManager->createInstances(Array)
#4 /var/www/pnm.com/html/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/Commands/MigrateToolsCommands.php(140): Drupal\migrate_tools\Commands\MigrateToolsCommands->migrationsList('', Array)
#5 [internal function]: Drupal\migrate_tools\Commands\MigrateToolsCommands->status('', Array)
#6 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(257): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(212): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->runCommandCallback(Array, Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
#8 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(176): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->validateRunAndAlter(Array, Array, Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
#9 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php(302): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->process(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), Array, Array, Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
#10 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->execute(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1000): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(255): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand), Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php(118): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php(49): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(72): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run(Array)
#17 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/drush/drush/drush(4): require('/var/www/pnm.co...')
#18 {main}. 
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration::getProcessNormalized() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/pnm.com/html/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/Migration.php on line 640 in /var/www/pnm.com/html/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/Migration.php on line 396 #0 /var/www/pnm.com/html/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/Migration.php(640): Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration->getProcessNormalized(NULL)
#1 /var/www/pnm.com/html/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/Migration.php(625): Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration->findMigrationDependencies(NULL)
#2 /var/www/pnm.com/html/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/MigrationPluginManager.php(122): Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration->getMigrationDependencies()
#3 /var/www/pnm.com/html/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/Commands/MigrateToolsCommands.php(701): Drupal\migrate\Plugin\MigrationPluginManager->createInstances(Array)
#4 /var/www/pnm.com/html/modules/contrib/migrate_tools/src/Commands/MigrateToolsCommands.php(140): Drupal\migrate_tools\Commands\MigrateToolsCommands->migrationsList('', Array)
#5 [internal function]: Drupal\migrate_tools\Commands\MigrateToolsCommands->status('', Array)
#6 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(257): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(212): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->runCommandCallback(Array, Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
#8 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(176): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->validateRunAndAlter(Array, Array, Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
#9 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php(302): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->process(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), Array, Array, Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
#10 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->execute(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1000): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(255): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand), Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php(118): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Drush\Symfony\DrushArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php(49): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(72): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run(Array)
#17 /var/www/pnm.com/vendor/drush/drush/drush(4): require('/var/www/pnm.co...')
#18 {main}
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration::getProcessNormalized() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/pnm.com/html/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/Migration.php on line 640 in Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration->getProcessNormalized() (line 396 of /var/www/pnm.com/html/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/Migration.php).
 [warning] Drush command terminated abnormally.
```

running other drush commands seems to work fine.

The yaml file I imported is:

```
id: loopy_releases_spreadsheet_import3
label: Import Casio Loopy releases
migration_groups:
  - releases

source:
  plugin: spreadsheet
  file: /var/www/pnm.com/imports/loopy.releases.ods
  worksheet: 'releases'
  origin: A2
  header_row: 1


  columns:
    - ID
    - 'Game Title'
    - 'System  ID'
    - 'Release Title'
    - 'Original Title (If Not English)'
    - Developer
    - Publisher
    - Label
    - Region
    - 'Release Day'
    - 'Release Month'
    - 'Release Year'
    - 'Manufacturer Code'
    - Barcode
    - Rarity
    - Description
    - 'Genres(s)'
    - Media
    - Body
    - Verified
    - 'Internal Notes'
    - Sources

  row_index_column: 'Row no.'

  keys:
    ID:
      type: string

  # Handle mapping of fields and processing here
  process:
    field_release_internal_id: ID
    title: 'Release Title'
    body: Description

  destination:
    plugin: entity:node
    default_bundle: release
```

The migration does not show up anywhere in structure migrations.

Looking at the import I did yesterday I can view the fields using:

```
vendor/bin/drush migrate:import article_csv_import
```

but looking at the import I just tried I get the same error as above:

```
vendor/bin/drush migrate:fields-source loopy_releases_spreadsheet_import
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I uninstalled all the migration module except for the base module, then I reinstalled them again. This seems to have cleared up the drush errors.

Answer (score 0):

You might just be missing dependencies...

```
type: module
name: Joomla Migrate
description: 'Joomla 3.5 to Drupal 8 migration.'
package: Migration
# core: 8.x
dependencies:
 - drupal:migrate
 - migrate_plus:migrate_plus
 - migrate_drupal_ui
 - migrate_tools
 - migrate_file

# version: '8.x-3.0-beta1'
# core: '8.x'

# Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2017-04-29
version: '8.x-1.x-dev'
core: '8.x'
project: 'joomla_migrate'
datestamp: 1493431790
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I have the following modules installed and enabled: migrate, migrate_plus, migrate_tools, migrate_source_csv, migrate_spreadsheet. I'm not upgrading from Joomla (or an earlier Drupal) this is just import fresh data from a spreadsheet (ods). I've installed the modules through composers so dependencies should all be installed.

Comment: https://understanddrupal.com/articles/migrating-microsoft-excel-and-libreoffice-calc-files-drupal.  You can get the Migrate Google Sheets module using composer: `composer require 'drupal/migrate_spreadsheet:^1.0'. This module depends on the `PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet` library and many PHP extensions including `ext-zip`. Check this page for a full list of dependencies. If any required extension is missing the installation will fail. If your Drupal site is not composer-based, you will not be able to use Migrate Spreadsheet, unless you go around a lot of hoops.

Comment: I installed it by using composer so all dependencies should be installed. The installation was successful. My setup had all been through composer.